# Importing only desired features from rxjs in angular 2 component

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I'm working on a angular 2 project bootstrapped with angular cli. I need the first load to be super quick. That's why trying to reduce all the bundle sizes.

What's pricking my head is the rxjs library as its increasing the bundle size significantly. I am looking for importing trickery for tree shaking to work, further reducing the chunk size. I've used vscode's suggestions for importing, they work while coding but upon building cli shows error of not resolving those paths.

This won't work

```
import { of } from 'rxjs/observable/of';
```

I had to resort to

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Rx';
```

Is there another way around to import the specific operators.

Comment: import 'rxjs/add/observable/of';

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the version of RxJs you use there are two ways of doing this.

With the older versions (< 6) you need to add all the operators, using something like:

```
import 'rxjs/add/observable/of'
```

and import Observable from

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
```

Importing from rxjs/Rx will actually fetch the whole library, so that's why it's not working for you. Also since the old way of importing will patch the Observable prototype you only need to import an operator once. Usually one will group them inside one single file per application and import only Observable in the places where it's neded.

In the new RxJs, starting with **version 6.0**, the way imports work was refactored especially for easier tree shaking, so one can simply import everything like:

```
import { Observable } from 'rxjs';
import { map, filter, switchMap } from 'rxjs/operators';
```